# AngularJS 1.4 ngNewRouter - How to use partial views?

Tags: angularjs, partial-views, partials, angularjs-new-router

I'm working on a project where I need to use the AngularJS 1.4.3.
The problem is that I have to use the new routing of course, but on a view I need to use another partial views.
E.g.
I have a Home view, and this contains 2 dynamic table generated by data from a REST call. These tables should be partial views depends on the user role, etc.
Because the 1.4 is brand new I've not found any correct tutorial, or documentation, how can I create these type of sub-components.

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: try using angular-ui router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: As far as I read this is deprecated in 1.4+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nested views, and therefore ng-viewports in views do not work at the moment, [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) is the current method of choice to accomplish this.

Edit:

I'am currently also working on a 1.4 project and we decided to use the next sprint to move to the ui router again, because of ngNewRouters many problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've got the same issue. Also I've dropped the partial views, and use simple views instead of partial ones. This solved the problem temporally.